# unable to access global assembly label data from c program linked with shared library

Tags: c, linux, assembly, shared-libraries

In my system, I have both static library file (libcrypto.a) and shared library (libcrypto.so.0.9.8).

**I am trying to access a global label AES_Td of an assembly file from inside a C program using static library and shared library.**

```
   //assembly code
.globl  AES_Td
.text
.align  64
AES_Td:
    .long   1353184337,1353184337
    .long   1399144830,1399144830
    .long   3282310938,3282310938
    .long   2522752826,2522752826
 .....
 .....

// test_glob.c
#include <stdio.h> 
extern void* AES_Td ;

int main()
{
    long *p;
    int i;
    p=(long *)(&AES_Td);
    printf("%p %lu\n",p,*p);
}
```

**Success with Static library**

While trying to link with static library, I am able to access the global label.

```
gcc -L. test_glob.c -lcrypto
```

**Segmentation fault with shared library**

I am getting following warning message while trying to link with shared library.

**/usr/bin/ld: warning: type and size of dynamic symbol `AES_Td' are not defined**

```
var=`pwd` 
gcc -g -L$var -O0 -Wall -o dynamic test_glob.c -lcrypto
/usr/bin/ld: warning: type and size of dynamic symbol `AES_Td' are not defined

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$var:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$var:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH


  ./dynamic 
segmentation fault
```

some post in SO suggest to create symlink to correctly linked with correct version of shared library to resolve the above error/warning message.

However in my case, although there exist symlink,

```
libcrypto.so -> libcrypto.so.0.9.8
```

**still I am getting same warning message and same segmentation fault error with symlink.**

I am using gcc in Debian OS.

Any help/link to solve segmentation fault or access above global label with shared library will be highly appreciated.

**EDIT-1: **

As per suggestion of Shachar Shemesh, I have re-compiled the crypto library again as follows

```
./config -fPIC -shared -DSTATIC_CRYPTO
make
```

then copied the libcrypto.a , libcrypto.so and libtomcrypto.so.0.9.8 into local folder.

Then I made changes the c code as follows,

```
// test_glob_modified.c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#ifdef STATIC_CRYPTO
extern void* AES_TD;
void** AES_Td_ptr= &AES_Td;
#else
void** AES_Td_ptr;
#endif

int main()
{

#ifndef STATIC_CRYPTO
AES_Td_ptr=dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"AES_Td");
#endif

        long *p;
        int i;
        p=(long *)(AES_Td_ptr);

        printf(" %p %lu\n", p,*p);

        return 0;

}



    #Compile and run the source code as follows 
    var=`pwd`
    gcc -g -L$var -Wall -o dynamic test_glob_modified.c -lcrypto -ldl

   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$var:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$var:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    ./dynamic
```

I am still getting Segmentation fault.

Comment: The linker will by default link with the shared library if there are both a shared and a static library. To force linking statically you need to use the `-static` option when linking.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I need to use shared library and as I said I am able to link with static library using mentioned command in post.

Comment: (as a sidenote, you could declare AES_td as `extern const long AES_td[];`, it won't solve your problem, but that would make using it much more natural: `printf("%lu", AES_td[0])`).

Comment: Hm, where exactly is the assembly code located you mention above?

Comment: But the linker will link with the dynamic library even in that case.That's the default. It should only link with `libcrypto.a` if it's the *only* `crypto` library in `./`.

Comment: I have copied the libcrypto.a and libcrypto.so.0.9.8 and libcrypto.so (symlink) in separate folder where test_glob.c is located. Although in original shared library creation time, assembly code is in different folder than .so or .a file .

Comment: What platform is this? For me the linking simply fails: `relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol 'AES_Td' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC`

Comment: @bholanath If an answer works for you, don't copy it into the question. Instead, just accept the answer (with or without upvoting it). If the answer does not solve your problem, use the comments section to ask follow-ups. Only edit the question if the **question** is incomplete.

Comment: @Shachar Shemesh I have accepted your solution as answer as it solved my problem of accessing global label data using shared library. Thank you so much.

Comment: @ShacharShemesh, I don't know what happened, now it is again giving segmentation fault. Thus I deselect the answer.

Comment: @bholanath if it worked, it is the solution. If it stopped working, you have another problem, and the best way is to ask a new question.

Comment: @ShacharShemesh, I simply rebooted the system and now it is not working. Now I am more confused, do this command gcc -g -L$var -Wall -o dynamic test_glob_modified.c -lcrypto -ldl link to dynamic or static library ? If it linked to dynamic then deletion of libcrypto.a should also worked, but in my case it is not working anymore.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is not possible in the way you are trying to do.

You cannot try to reference `.text` area data by absolute value from a shared object. On some platforms it doesn't work, on others it fails the link. For example, on X86_64:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: type and size of dynamic symbol `AES_Td' are not defined
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc4xpr2u.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `AES_Td' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The reason is that text segment code is loaded through a stub that resolves the actual address upon first use. Your direct use of the symbol bypasses this mechanism.

The solution I suggest is to compile the static version with `-DSTATIC_CRYPTO`. Change the code like so:

```
#ifdef STATIC_CRYPTO
extern void* AES_Td;
void** AES_Td_ptr = &AES_Td;
#else
void** AES_Td_ptr;
#endif

...

  // Somewhere near the start of the program
#ifndef STATIC_CRYPTO
  AES_Td_ptr = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "AES_Td");
#endif
```

Access the actual code via the `AES_Td_ptr` pointer (which simply replaces `p` in your sample program). In essence, you are manually writing the same code the linker places as stub for regular function access.

Also note that the two methods are exclusive. While `AES_Td_ptr = &AES_Td` won't work for dynamic linking, it should also be noted that the `dlsym` method won't work for static linking. You need both if you want to support both.

**EDITED TO ADD**

If you can change the library you're linking, and the symbol you are looking for is not actually code, then moving it into the `.rodata` section instead of `.text` would work with the same code for both static and dynamic linking. If this is not your library, or the symbol actually contains code, then I'm afraid what I wrote is the best you can hope for.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need `dlsym` to access globals from a shared library.  The compiler emits code to get the address from the GOT when you use the value of a global.  https://godbolt.org/g/5M3xWt.

Comment: @Shachar Shemesh, as I mentioned in my post I am able to access global label AES_Td with static library (libcrypto.a). I am asking for solution to access AES_Td with shared library libcrypto.so.0.9.8 or symlink libtomcrypt.so

Comment: @Shachar Shemesh, do I need to pass -DSTATIC_CRYPTO parameter in ./config command?

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, but who initializes the GOT entry? For data, that happens by the dynamic linker. Notice, however, that the OP was about code (i.e. - text segment). The dynamic linker does not initialize those entries, instead relying on stubs that do, essentially, what my code does.

Comment: @bholanath, I'm not sure what `./config` is. `-DSTATIC_CRYPTO` needs to be passed to the compiler compiling the code where you are trying to access AES_Td.

Comment: @ShacharShemesh: I think the right answer is to tell the OP to put their table in `section .rodata`, so the dynamic linker will do it for them.  That section (along with the `.text` section) goes into the text *segment* of the library.  (Linking, including dynamic linking, cares about sections, not just segments.)  Anyway, good point, I think you're right that with lazy dynamic linking, the GOT entries for `section .text` symbols aren't updated early.  Non-lazy dynamic linking would be another solution, which is supported.  (There's even `gcc -fno-plt`)

Comment: @PeterCordes It's a good solution *if* OP can do it. I believe he can't. The numbers he put there disassemble into valid code. I believe the only reason the example looks this way is because he made an MVP, and the original problem is about actual code.

Comment: I think it's just data.  It's definitely not sane x86-64 code; the disassembly includes `hlt` (halt the machine, privileged instruction) and just doesn't look sensible.  ARM32 `objdump` doesn't make any sense of it either.  Most bit-pattern disassemble to some x86 instructions but that's just because the coding space is mostly full and many instructions don't have any reserved bits.  (x86 is a mess after so many years of ISA extensions, but just being a variable-length ISA means it's natural to use up most of the coding space.)

Comment: @Shachar Shemesh , when I try to compile the above code with -DSTATIC_CRYPTO as you said for static, I got error  AES_Td undeclared.

Comment: @Shachar Shemesh, I am accepting this answer as It solved my problem of accessing global label using shared library.

Comment: @bholanath as before, you still need to declare the variable. I'll amend the answer to incorporate it. It was not meant to be complete.

Comment: @ShacharShemesh, after I delete the libcrypto.a , libcrypto.so and libcrypto.so.0.9.8 from local folder, I try to compile using  gcc -g -Wall -o dynamic test_.c -lcrypto -ldl -fPIC . Compilation is successful , it means it is able to locate libcrypto.so in /usr/lib folder and link with it (instead of local folder). However, it gives segmentation fault while trying to run. Any suggestion to resolve ?

Comment: @ShacharShemesh, I tried to run again by copying libcrypto.a , libcrypto.so and libcrypto.so.0.9.8 into local folder. I am now getting segmentation fault although yesterday I was able to run and get result. No idea what happened.

Comment: This is a new question, but here's the answer anyways: You need to supply `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` if you want to load libraries not from the standard path. Next time, ask new questions if you want to solve different problems.

Comment: @ShacharShemesh, I have supplied LD_LIBRARY_PATH and still I am getting segmentation fault. Also I think without LD_LIBRARY_PATH it shows different error like something not defined in present scope.  I used these, LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$var:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$var:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: @ShacharShemesh, dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"AES_Td") returns null. it means it is unable to find AES_Td symbol.

Comment: @bholanath thank you for approaching me. As I said above, this is a new question. Feel free to ask it as such, and hope that *someone* will answer it.